# I'm using iron:router v1.0.7 but this.render() is "undefined". I can't see what I'm doing wrong

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I'm displaying an access denied template when the visitor tries to visit the Submit page. This works fine. Here is the code:

```
Router.route('/', {name: 'etoeventsList'});
Router.route('/submit', {name: 'etoeventSubmit'});

var requireLogin = function () {
  if (!Meteor.user()) {
    this.render('accessDenied');
  } else {
    this.next();
  }
};

Router.onBeforeAction(requireLogin, {only: 'etoeventSubmit'});
```

I want to utilize "requireLogin" under a different context (anonymous user visiting '/') so I thought I would add an argument to allow me to pass in the template to be rendered. Like this:

```
var requireLogin = function (template) { // now with argument 'template'
  if (!Meteor.user()) {
    this.render(template); // using 'template'
  } else {
    this.next();
  }
};

Router.onBeforeAction(requireLogin('accessDenied'), {only: 'etoeventSubmit'}); // passing 'accessDenied'
Router.onBeforeAction(requireLogin('index'), {only: 'etoeventsList'}); // passing 'index'
```

The error I receive is `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` and the template I want to show does not display.

Comment: While I figure out how to do that, can you explain why this works without the function argument (the first block of code)?

Comment: Sorry, I read the question wrong. I think the issue is trying to use two different 'only' options. I've never tried this approach, personally.

Comment: I'm not finding anything in the documentation that states you can use "only" once globally.

Comment: Can you describe any errors you are getting or what is actually happening?

Comment: The error I receive is `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` and the template I want to show does not display. I think I'll try to reproduce this in a new meteor app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it that way. The way you are doing it, **this** will refer to **Window**. You will have to use an anonymous function as a param to **onBeforeAction**.

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'layout',
    loadingTemplate: 'loading',
    notFoundTemplate: 'notFound',
    waitOn: function() {

    }
});

if(Meteor.isClient) {
  Router.onBeforeAction(function() {
    // is user logged in
    if (! Meteor.user()) {
      if (Meteor.loggingIn()) {
        this.render('loading');
      } else {
        this.render('accessDenied');
      }
    } else {
      this.next();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I don't see how that can be true. The first code block I show works fine. The only change I've made is to an an argument to the `requireLogin` function. Also, it is the example given in the Discover Meteor book.

Comment: It's mainly about scope. You are using the **this* of the requireLogin function. What you need is the context of the Router, but you can't get to it (that I am aware of). I tried something like Router.onBeforeAction(Router.current(), requireLogin('accessDenied'), {only: 'etoeventSubmit'}); then in requireLogin your first param would be that context: requireLogin(context, template). Make sense? But, like I said, I was unable to get the context of the router.

Comment: Well, you're right. But the fact that the first example works makes this more mysterious to me. Considering all that, is it possible to make this DRY?

Comment: I see what you mean. I did try Router.onBeforeAction(requireLogin... without the () and it works fine. Let me think about this a little more...

Comment: @giraffeslacks One thing I thought of was the fact that you are passing the callback by value and not by reference. When you were calling requireLogin, without parentheses, that is by reference; you are not calling the function, but allowing the Router to do that later. Calling requireLogin(), with parentheses, is by value; so you would be getting the return value of requireLogin. And at that time the **this** inside that function would be the Window context. So the question would be: how would you call requireLogin as a reference **and** pass values? I really don't know.

Comment: I see I see. That makes sense. I was pretty sure it would come down to a misunderstanding of something (how Meteor works or JavaScript.)